# How do I allow autoloading of custom libraries in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, autoload

Hi I am using CakePHP and there are some Vendor files I need to add to the autoloading. Is this the correct method:

In the bootstrap.php, I have the following code:

```
function __autoload($className){

        $classFile = '../vendors/phprtf/' . str_replace('_', '/', $className) . '.php';

        // check if file exists
         if(file_exists($classFile)) {
            require $classFile;
        }

}
```

The PHPRTFLite has a lot of class files under various sub directories. So listing all of them is not a good option.

It seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) for the flexibility it offers.

> If your code has an existing `__autoload` function then this function
>   must be explicitly registered on the `__autoload` stack. This is because
>   `spl_autoload_register()` will effectively replace the engine cache for
>   the `__autoload` function by either `spl_autoload()` or
>   `spl_autoload_call()`.
>
> If there must be multiple autoload functions, `spl_autoload_register()`
>   allows for this. It effectively creates a queue of autoload functions,
>   and runs through each of them in the order they are defined. By
>   contrast, `__autoload()` may only be defined once.

Comment: Hello Alex, did you mean like this:

function loader($className){

 $classFile = '../vendors/phprtf/' . str_replace('_', '/', $className) . '.php';

 // check if file exists
  if(file_exists($classFile)) {
  require $classFile;
 }
}

spl_autoload_register('loader');

Comment: thank you very much. I have tried this and I put this in the loader function: debug($classFile); I can see that this loader function is being called even when the PHPRTFLite classes are not required (example output: ../vendors/phprtf/Router.php). Does it mean that by default PHP will always call all the autload functions?

Comment: Actually, with or without the spl_autoload_register the function is being called several times even if there are no PHPRTFLite classes in use. Is this normal?

Comment: @Tony It may require the `Router.php` file so it knows what URLs go where. I'm not familiar with the framework so I can't tell you anything more I'm afraid.

Comment: Hello Alex, thank you very much for your help. Yes, it needs Router.php and many other files. But my (may be silly) question is, does PHP call all the functions registered with spl_autoload_register every time it needs to auto load a class? Is that normal?

Comment: @Tony It does call them all. It sounds like a lot of work for PHP to do, but I've never found it to be the bottleneck of any of my applications.